# Variable almacenada con localStorage desde PHP no se muestra

Tags: php

Tengo una variable en PHP llamada `$output` la cual al hacer un `var_dump()` muestra los siguientes datos:

```
C:\wamp64\www\ecuservi\profile\retornarventa.php:12:
object(Transbank\Webpay\wsTransactionDetailOutput)[9]
  public 'authorizationCode' => string '1415' (length=4)
  public 'paymentTypeCode' => string 'VD' (length=2)
  public 'responseCode' => int 0
  public 'sharesNumber' => int 0
  public 'amount' => string '11900' (length=5)
  public 'commerceCode' => string '597020000540' (length=12)
  public 'buyOrder' => string '849401686' (length=9)
```

En el código PHP quiero almacenar las variables con `localStorage` para mostrarlas en otro archivo:

```
$tokenWs = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'token_ws');
$result = $transaction->getTransactionResult($tokenWs);
$output = $result->detailOutput;
var_dump($output);
if($output->responseCode == 0){


    echo '<script>window.localStorage.clear();</script>';
    echo '<script>window.localStorage.setItem("codigoautorizacion",'.$output->authorizationCode.');</script>';
    echo '<script>window.localStorage.setItem("tipopago",'.$output->paymentTypeCode.');</script>';
    echo '<script>window.localStorage.setItem("precio",'.$output->amount.');</script>';
    echo '<script>window.localStorage.setItem("ordencompra",'.$output->buyOrder.');</script>';
    echo '<script>window.localStorage.setItem("numerotarjeta",'.$result->cardDetail->cardNumber.');</script>';  
    echo '<script>window.localStorage.setItem("responseCode",'.$output->responseCode.');</script>';
}
```

Pero por más que lo intento resulta ser que la variable `paymentTypeCode` no se muestra en la otra página, pero sí lo hacen las demás variables, al hacer un `console.log(tipopago)` muestra `null`.

¿Cómo puedo lograr obtener dicha variable?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Precio <span id="precio"></span></p>
    <p>Codigo  <span id="codigoautorizacion"></span></p>
    <p>Tarjeta  <span id="numerotarjeta"></span></p>
    <p>N° Orden  <span id="ordencompra"></span></p>
    <p>Tipo Pago  <span id="tipopago"></span></p>   
    <script>
        document.getElementById('precio').innerHTML = window.localStorage.getItem('precio');
        document.getElementById('codigoautorizacion').innerHTML = window.localStorage.getItem('codigoautorizacion');
        document.getElementById('numerotarjeta').innerHTML = window.localStorage.getItem('numerotarjeta');
        document.getElementById('ordencompra').innerHTML = window.localStorage.getItem('ordencompra');
        document.getElementById('tipopago').innerHTML = window.localStorage.getItem('tipopago');
        console.log(window.localStorage.getItem('paymentTypeCode'));
    </script>   
</body>
</html>

Precio 11900

Codigo 1415

Tarjeta 7763

N° Orden 849401686

Tipo Pago
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el HTML generado por el código PHP? ¿Te aparece algún mensaje de error en la consola de depuración de javascript? Además, ¡¿estás intentando buscar por `id` elementos que aún no han sido generados en el DOM?!

Comment: El Html es lo último que se ve en la publicación, desde donde dice precio 11900 hacia abajo, son esas 5 líneas que se se generan en el html, y la única variable que no se muestra es paymentTypeCode, las demás si se muestran

Comment: ¿Podrías comprobar si mi respuesta solucionó tus problemas? Además, por si no lo sabías, podrías usar un único registro del almacenamiento interno del navegador para almacenar todos los valores. Si lo deseas te indico cómo hacerlo (**simplifica muchísimo tu código**).

Comment: He agregado lo que te comenté a mi respuesta. Si tienes alguna duda sobre su funcionamiento házmelo saber en un comentario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu código veo varios fallos que deberías corregir. Algunos están relacionados con tu problema y otros están relacionados con problemas de seguridad, ya que tu código es vulnerable a [ataques XSS (coss-site scripting)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Para empezar, modificaré la manera en la que guardas los valores desde javascript:

```
if ($output->responseCode == 0) {
    ?><script>
        window.localStorage.clear();
        window.localStorage.setItem(
            "codigoautorizacion",
            <?= json_encode($output->authorizationCode) ?>
        );
        window.localStorage.setItem(
            "tipopago",
            <?= json_encode($output->paymentTypeCode) ?>
        );
        window.localStorage.setItem(
            "precio",
            <?= json_encode($output->amount) ?>
        );
        window.localStorage.setItem(
            "ordencompra",
            <?= json_encode($output->buyOrder) ?>
        );
        window.localStorage.setItem(
            "numerotarjeta",
            <?= json_encode($result->cardDetail->cardNumber) ?>
        );
        window.localStorage.setItem(
            "responseCode",
            <?= json_encode($output->responseCode) ?>
        );
    </script><?php
}
```

Cambios realizados:

- Una única etiqueta `<script>` para todo el código javascript, no es necesario una por cada línea.
- He salido de PHP para generar con sencillez el código HTML/javascript, en vez de ir haciendo salidas parciales con `echo` línea a línea.
- **La única forma segura** de enviar datos desde PHP a javascript (evitando XSS y otros problemas relacionados) es haciendo uso de [`json_encode()`](https://php.net/json).

En el lado de la página que debe mostrar esos valores, vamos a esperar a que se genere el DOM antes de acceder a elementos por su `id` usando el evento [`Events.DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) de la siguiente manera:

```
<script>
    /* No ejecutamos el siguiente código hasta que el DOM haya sido generado */
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
        document.getElementById('precio').innerText = window.localStorage.getItem('precio');
        document.getElementById('codigoautorizacion').innerText = window.localStorage.getItem('codigoautorizacion');
        document.getElementById('numerotarjeta').innerText = window.localStorage.getItem('numerotarjeta');
        document.getElementById('ordencompra').innerText = window.localStorage.getItem('ordencompra');
        document.getElementById('tipopago').innerText = window.localStorage.getItem('tipopago');
        console.log(window.localStorage.getItem('paymentTypeCode'));
    });
</script>
```

Esto te permitirá poder mover el código javascript a un archivo externo y no preocuparte de que se ejecute antes o después del HTML que debe acceder.

Además, he cambiado `innerHTML` a `innerText` para evitar, de nuevo, problemas relacionados con XSS (caracteres HTML que se puedan malinterpretar).

---

Te sugiero una forma alternativa sugerida para simplificar tu código.

En la parte que guardas los datos:

```
if ($output->responseCode == 0) {
    ?><script>
        window.localStorage.clear();
        window.localStorage.setItem(
            "result",
            JSON.stringify(<?= json_encode($result) ?>)
        );
    </script>DATOS ALMACENADOS<?php
}
```

Como no se puedan guardar datos sin serializar en `localStorage`, hago uso de `JSON.stringify` para convertir el objeto JSON generado desde PHP a una cadena que se pueda almacenar.

En la parte que lee los datos:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    /* Obtenemos los datos almacenados */
    let result = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("result"));
    document.getElementById('precio').innerText = result.detailOutput.amount;
    document.getElementById('codigoautorizacion').innerText = result.detailOutput.authorizationCode;
    document.getElementById('numerotarjeta').innerText = result.cardDetail.cardNumber;
    document.getElementById('ordencompra').innerText = result.detailOutput.buyOrder;
    document.getElementById('tipopago').innerText = result.detailOutput.paymentTypeCode;
    console.log(result.detailOutput.paymentTypeCode);
});
```

Tienes el código de esta respuesta funcionando en los siguientes enlaces:

- Github: https://github.com/ojgarciab/423791-stackoverflow-es
- Gitpod (probar en línea): http://gitpod.io/#https://github.com/ojgarciab/423791-stackoverflow-es

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado, su respuesta me a funcionado a la perfección